# Any function like LOOKUP in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services

There is any function like LOOKUP in 2008 apart of sub reports because i have a  tablix from where the columns are coming from different datasets.

Answer (score 0):

No. SSRS took big leaps forward with 2008R2. I recommend installing a more recent version of SSRS, which could still connect to a SQL 2008 server four your datasources.

Alternately, change your queries to combine the fields in the dataset.